# Exception Stacktrace logs using %throwable in log4j.properties file not fully loaded

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j

I am trying to stacktrace content oin the logs , however only the first line of the stacktrace is populating in server logs.

I have the configuration as below.

log4j.appender.layout.Conversionpattern={"timestamp":"%d{yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS}","exception":{"source":"%l","stacktrace":"%throwable{10}"},"additionalinfo":{}}

Not: i have tried the conversionpattern for stacktrace as follows, %throwable{}, %throwable{0}, %throwable{1}

Output: stacktrace : java.lang.nullPointerException

all the conditions return only the first line of the stack trace

Need the suggestion to get the full logs for the stacktrace.

Comment: can you share the code how are you logging ?

Comment: try { ...} catch { case e : Exception => logger.error ( message=s"Exception",e)

Comment: error log as follows public void error (object message, throwable t )